# disable windows font size increase in my C# application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, font-size

I built a windows application in C# that is very size specific. I hard coded the size of the form so that it could not be resized. The problem is when someone changes there windows settings to font size for example (125% or 150%) my application breaks and buttons get moved over, and things fall off of screen. The entire application is a mess.

Is there a way in C# to disable the custom font effects of windows and use the pre-set font I told it to use in my form. I want all windows custom features to be turned to default on my application.

Is this possible at all, like import a DLL and call a function or change my program.cs some how.

Comment: Which UI framework? (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, LightSwitch?)

Comment: I almost feel like downvoting for this. I often need to increase font size to be able to see the screen, at least on some monitors. Fix your application to properly adjust, don't prevent adjustment because you can't be bothered to fix your application.

Comment: Quickest way to make autoscaling work is by selecting all the controls with Ctrl+A, right-click the Font property in the Properties grid and clicking Reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. Write your application so it adapts to the user's selected font size.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how. No matter what I try, even disabling the specific size portions, everything gets messed up. If you are going to tell me to do something, then tell me how to do it where to learn.

Comment: @user1078510, I suggest you ask another question: "How do I make my form scale when the user changes the windows font size". I suspect you are just using the wrong method to set the specific size portions. How are you making the size fixed?